# Conditional SSR with Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, conditional-statements, server-side-rendering

I'm building a website with Next.js hosted on Netlify and I want to restrict access to the staging environment and allow it on production by checking users ips against my ip whitelist.

To do that I need to use `getServerSideProps` where I get the IP from headers and compare it. On staging, I don't need this functionality and the same pages should not have this funtionality.
It looks like `getServerSideProps` can't be run conditionally based on env variables, so I'm currently stuck with it.

Maybe someone had experience with same problem or can advice alternative approaches?

Comment: You can access the environment variable inside your getServerSideProps like process.env.YourKey and handle this logic?

Comment: _"It looks like `getServerSideProps` can't be run conditionally based on env variables"_ - What do you mean exactly? While it's true that `getServerSideProps` will run on every page request, you can control what it runs inside based on environment variables.

Comment: @juliomalves getServerSideProps and getStaticProps can't be used inside the page simultaneously. Plus you can't wrap getServerSideProps in condition. I resolved this issue with babel plugin and removing getServerSideProps from the code on build time.

Comment: My point was, you can have the condition inside the `getServerSideProps` instead. Feel free to add the solution you found as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @juliomalves as I said before, getServerSideProps has to be a result of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was found within next.js itself. They released the plugin for Nettlify a couple of days ago, and now they support next js redirects.
[Essential Next.js plugin v4 release notes](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-nextjs/blob/main/docs/release-notes/v4.md)